# Greensock GSAP animate <li> in ajax for loop

Tags: jquery, ajax, gsap

I would like my `<li>` to animate in as they load from an Ajax load. Here is my code that works with the annimation but it annimates ALL `<li>`'s loaded.

**How can I animate each individually as they load?**

```
success: function( json_data )
{
for( var i = 0; i < json_data.length; i++ )
{

// if user has no image sets default
if(json_data[i].author=="")
json_data[i].author ='http://lorempixel.com/250/250/'; 

console.log("jsonData: " , json_data[i]);

var rainingPhrase = $(".timeline-normal");
var tl = new TimelineLite();

var new_html = [

'<li class="timeline-normal" id="' + json_data[i].date +'"">',
'<div class="timeline-badge" style="background-image: url(' + json_data[i].author +' )">',
'</div>',
'<div class="timeline-date">',
'<time datetime="' + json_data[i].date + '"></time>',
'</div>',
'<div class="timeline-panel">',
'<a href="json_data[i].url">',
'<div class="popover left">',
'<div class="arrow"></div>',
'<h3 class="popover-title">' + json_data[i].title + '</h3>',
'<div class="popover-content">',
'<p><small>' + json_data[i].description +'</small></p>',
'</div>',
'</div>',
'</a>',
'</div>',
'</li>'
].join( '\n' );

jQuery('.get_more_topics').before( new_html );
jQuery('.get_more_topics').before( more_button );

/// HERE ARE THE LINES I NEED HELP WITH
tl.add(TweenLite.set(rainingPhrase, {bottom: 250}));
tl.add(TweenLite.to(rainingPhrase, 2, {bottom:5, ease: Bounce.easeOut}));

jQuery('#temp_loader').remove();
jQuery('.get_more_topics').show(); 
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've got three problems:

1. A `TimelineLite` instance is created inside of a loop and your `rainingPhrase` variable is also collecting elements inside of a loop. A loop which is in progress.
2. Each of the `TimelineLite` instances receive **ALL** of the list-items, thanks to `rainingPhrase` variable.
3. What this then tells each `TimelineLite` instance is to animate **ALL** of the **LIs** at once because, by default, they are all added to **0-th** position. (I suggest you take a look at this to [understand the position parameter](http://greensock.com/position-parameter)).

Solution perhaps could be:

1. Take your `tl` variable outside of your loop so you have one timeline rather than many. Do the same to `rainingPhrase` variable. Place them both **AFTER** the loop.
2. Add `{paused: true}` to the constructor of the timeline so that it remains paused while everything is being added i.e. `var tl=new TimelineLite({paused: true});`.
3. Instead of using `add` method, I suggest you to use `staggerFromTo` method since you want to set an initial state for each of your list items as well as you want them to place your tweens either exactly one after or overlapping them just a little bit. So the code becomes: `tl.staggerFromTo(rainingPhrase, 2, {bottom: 250}, {bottom: 5, ease: Bounce.easeOut}, .2);`. This **.2** is the stagger value. [Look it up here](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TimelineLite/staggerFromTo/).
4. And finally, play the timeline i.e. `tl.play();`.

Having said all that, you probably don't even need to use `TimelineLite`. You can use `TweenMax` and achieve the same thing. [Take a look at this JSFiddle for example](http://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/m8ebpfom/3/).